# Data type validation using jQuery Validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

How would i validate the data type of a form input(of type text) element?
For example i want to have only floating point numbers when i submit the form.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="user-id"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please show us your code.  Also please don't tag-spam your question with irrelevant tags.  If it's not mentioned, or a relevant part of the question, it should not be a tag.

Comment: Hey..I am newbie to jquery...I dont know how to use jquery validator plugin to perform such type of validations

Comment: Hey, people here expect you to put in a little effort yourself along with a more gracious attitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ULZaz/1/**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').validate({
        rules: {
            'user-name': {
                required: true,
                number: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
             'user-name': {
                 required: "this is the custom message for required",
                 number: "this is the custom message for number"
             }
        }
    })
});​
```

[**Documentation**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#save-number").validate({
                errorClass: "validationClass",
                rules:{
                    tempNumber:{
required:true,
number:true


}
                    
                    

                    
                },
                messages:{
                    tempNumber: "*"

                }
            });
Can i different messages for required and number validations?
bcoz this will always display asterisk.

Comment: @user1831612, Explain context of what are you giving me here.  Please use the "edit" button and _append_ the relevant code into your OP.

Comment: Sorry That was a copy paste error

Comment: @user1831612, Yes, you can use different messages for each rule.  I'll update my answer now.